# Oracle String to Date "2013-10-15T20:12:56.24584+0100"

Tags: oracle, datetime

I got a TIMESTAMP string, need to convert in Oracle to datetime, I try several format mask but fail, any idea?

```
to_timestamp('2013-10-15T20:12:56.24584+0100','YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.SSSSSTZHTZM')
```

Comment: Can you explain the date format you have? especially the last part after second(24584+0100). You have interpreted this as seconds past midnight. I tried to_timestamp('2013-10-15T20:12:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'). It works till here. When I add SSSSS, it throws the error "hour conflicts with seconds in day". So, I think you are missing some information or you interpretation is wrong.

Comment: The date format I got was really data from other system, that data transfer to us with file and need to be handled.  Just like answer below, TZH means Time Zone hour, TZM means Time Zone minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this right, you should:

1. Use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` function.
2. Use `FF` format for fractional seconds instead of `SSSSS`.
3. Enclose the literal `T` in quotation marks like this: `"T"`.

This works:

```
SELECT
  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2013-10-15T20:12:56.24584+0100','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZHTZM')
FROM dual;
```